# Port & Adapter Pattern - invoke multiple implementation of same output port

Tags: java, architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I have some doubt about how implement a simple scenario for a my style exercises following the Hexagonal architecture or Port & Adapter Pattern.

I have a UseCase (or service) that has to send a Contact (received from a contact form) to an external API service.

```java
public class SendContactUseCase{

    //output port interface
    private final SendContact sendContact;

    public ServiceLayer(SendContact sendContact) {
        this.sendContact = sendContact;
    }

    public void sendContact(ContactRequest req){
        sendContact.send(req);
    }
}
```

So I have create an output port with a method `send(ContactRequest req)` after that I have implemented this interface as a driven adapter where I put the codes for the communication with the API

```java
//driven adapter
public class SendContactToAPIAdapter implements SendContact {
   
    //private final PossibleAPILib possibleAPIlib...;

    @Override
    public boolean send(ContactRequest req) {
    //HERE the code to communicate with API
    }
}
```

Here my doubt, what if at a later moment comes the need to send the "Contact" **also** to another channel, for example as XML attachment to a specific email address.

If I have understood correctly the Port & Adapter pattern to hide the infrastructure "logic" to the UseCase I should implement a new driven adapter from the same Port in order to inject the correct adapter in the UseCase.

```java
public class SendContactXMLAdapter implements SendContact
```

But if I'd should invoke both the adapater? Beacause I have to send the contact to the both systems?
Should I to create a third adapter where hide the logic to call both systems?

I hope I've been clear
Thanks folks

Create a sample java project for a simple use case

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you actually want to accomplish.

To me, your anticipation of the 'need to send the "Contact" also to another channel' sounds like an additional feature of your business logic.

Based on that assumption, I would implement two separate port/adapter pairs, one for the API and one for XML. Your use case can then decide which ports to call.

This diagram visualizes what I mean: [Component Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mlll.png)

If you really always want to send the contact to the API *and* export it as XML you could leave your use-case untouched and just extend the implementation of your `SendContactToAPIAdapter` to do both. But you should then also consider renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface ContactRegisterer{
   public void registerContact(Contact contactToRegister) throws ContactRegisterException;
}
```

you could **use this interface[represents a port which is used by more higher level logic of your application] so that the location of where to save the contact and how to save it could be changed independently from the client.** This interface **could be used to register contact to a single but different destinations, or to multiple and different destination.** For instance, you could register to a file, a database, a service or all of them.

When you register to a single destination, all you need is to **give a different implementation of the interface for registering to that destination.**

When you register to multiple destinations, **you could use Decorator design pattern.** (Create a wrapper that implements the interface and also contains different objects implementing the same interface. The wrapper is given to the client(have the same interface, hence the client is not aware of the fact that it is given a wrapper), the wrapper in turn could use multiple threads for registering to each destination or use a for loop within a thread)

Another alternative is to use **A Modified Version Of Chain of Responsibility pattern.** In this pattern, you chain multiple(open ended) instances of the interface and every instance call the next after it is done registering to its destination.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the change is a technical change or a business logic change.

The ports and adapters architecture allows you to change the adapters without changing the Core of the application. If you have tests that validate your business logic, as you should, you'll see that you can swap adapters, everything will work fine and you won't have to change your Core tests. In this case, you can have the two adapters and configure one or the other based on some setting, or as you say, have an adapter that basically calls the other two.

On the other hand, if your business logic requirements change (depending on some business rule you have to send the contact to A or to B), you'll notice that you'll have to change your tests to verify the new requirements. In that case, your Core will define a different Port that will be more suited to the new business logic.